# XCode adding duplicate and incorrect icon filenames to Info.plist

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4.3, info.plist

When I run the XCode 'Archive' command, I get seven error messages about missing files.  Most are for the launch files that are supposed to be there, but one contains the misspelling "Portait".

```
warning: Icon specified in the Info.plist not found under the top level app wrapper: Default-Portait~ipad.png (-19007)
Unable to validate your application. - (null)
```

I did enter that filename by mistake several months ago, but I thought I expunged it from the project.  Here is the 'Info.plist' file for my app.  Note that it has no icon entries, other than **Icon file**.

[image: Info.plist for app]

Here is my Target Summary.  I have launch images specified.

[image: XCode Target Summary]

When I look at the 'Info.plist' file within the newly created archive, it contains a whole list of icons.  I've showing **Icon files (iOS 5)** here, but the list is duplicated under **Icon files**.  The "Portait" misspelling is there, as are several duplicates.  It's mess.

[image]

I know that XCode automatically generates some content for 'Info.plist', but *where* is this long list of filenames coming from?  And, how can I prevent them being generated?

### What I Have Tried

1. I have run 'Clean' and deleted my XCode 'DerivedData' directory, but the warning messages and spurious Info.plist entries persist.
2. I checked the localized 'InfoPlist.strings', but it only contains the line `/* Localized versions of Info.plist keys */`.
3. I looked through the contents of my '.xcodeproj' package, but found no mention of the files it's trying to find.
4. I tried adding an empty array of icon files to my 'Info.plist', or adding the names of the exact files I wanted.  The bad and duplicate names still get appended to the end when I Archive.
5. I tried duplicating the Target (which, as usual, duplicated the existing `Info.plist` file).  Archiving the new target resulted in the same error.
6. The Build Setting **Preprocess Info.plist File** was off.  I tried switching it on; it made no difference.
7. I tried switching off the Build Setting **Expand Build Settings in Info.Plist File**.  It told that I was trying to run the file '${EXECUTABLE_NAME}'.  I went to my 'Info.plist' and changed **Executable file** from '${EXECUTABLE_NAME}' to a hard-coded text value, and also manually replaced the other '${...}' entries.  Despite this, it persists in trying to run '${EXECUTABLE_NAME}'.  Possibly whatever is adding to the icon settings is also overriding my executable name.

### What I Would Rather Not Do

I could probably suppress the warning by adding files to the project with the names it expects, including `Default-Portait~ipad.png`.  I'd really rather stop it these names being added to 'Info.plist' in the first place, since those duplicate entries could cause other problems down the line.

### Other Details

This project was created in early 2011, and has been progressively migrated through newer versions of XCode.  It is currently open in XCode Version 4.3.2 (4E2002).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it: choose a Target and go to the 'Info' tab, and you get something that looks like 'Info.plist'... but changes made there can override your Info.plist.  This was especially confusing because I had intentionally made multiple Targets share the same 'Info.plist' file, to avoid needing to make the same change in multiple places.

I would still welcome an explanation of where these settings are stored within the '.xcodeproj' package.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue -- Xcode did this to me for a new project.  My info tab on the target shows the same mess. I guess I will check for updated iOS6 docs and edit the entries here to the best form.